# What is this Lego piece - Yellow with handles and an octagonal section?

Tags: part-identification

It clearly says Lego on it, but I have no idea what it is.  The only number inside is 4-01. [image: yellow Lego piece]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a "[Underwater Scooter](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30092)". It's a handheld device to propel a diver forward.

Similar devices can be seen in the James Bond movie "[Thunderball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderball_(film))".

Answer (score 6):

This is part is commonly found in the Divers theme back in the late 90's (http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Town/subtheme-Divers)  The part in question is a minifigure accessory:

http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30092

Comment: For what it's worth, the "underwater"-themed AlphaTeam sets also had this piece, but in black.